# Only the Homepage is showing after moving Magento

Tags: database, importexport, core-config-data

I've just moved a Magento website to another server and domain.
I adjusted the secure and unsecure url path in the cofig data table and also adjusted the config.xml. After that i've also cleared the cache.

Something strange happens now on the new domain.

When i enter the url in my browser it shows me the homepage, so i was happy at first.
Sadly it does only that. Al the links in the menu don't work and also the backend isn't approachable. I also checked this in de db-table, the path is correct.

So only the homepage is showing correct, everything else seems like it isn't there.

Does anybody have a clue on what's going wrong here?

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the `.htaccess` file in place. It might not be copied when moving the shop

Answer (score 3):

If the link `mysite.com/index.php/customer/account/login` works but `mysite.com/customer/account/login` get's you 404 then you don't have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your new server.
Enable it and it should work.

Comment: Or the .htaccess wasn't moved. When unpacking and using the `mv` command youhave to mention .htaccess explicitly. Speaking from experience sadly...

Comment: Awesome, i think you just solved my problem. In wich table i can enable mod_rewrite?

Comment: I don't know what server you use, but here are some details about mod rewrite. For [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and for [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule). You cannot enable it from a table. But first check what @SanderMangel said. maybe the htaccess was not moved.

Comment: web/seo/use_rewrites in the config-data table is value '1', wich is 'yes' for as far is my knowledge goes ;)

Comment: Do i have a problem when i don't have access to the old server anymore? The backup is from a year ago.

Comment: P.S: The server has rewrites enabled, i moved it from another server but the same hoster, so i guess that isn't the problem?

Comment: @Kevin create a file with just `phpinfo();` to be sure. And set `web/seo/use_rewrites` to `0` for testing purposes, oh and please turn cache off while moving

Comment: Hi Sander, so the file i have to create is called .htacces with the contents phpinfo() ?

Comment: I've just uploaded a new .htaccess to my files. it's working!!  Thanks for helping out!

Comment: @SanderMangel. Please put your comment as an answer. It seams that was the correct one.

Comment: @Kevin. Please mark the answer that Sander is going to post as accepted.

Comment: Done :) glad to have helped